# Quick access to deeply nested values in Objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, data-structures

I have a data structure like this:

```
LAYOUT = {
  'Picking Type 1': {
    1: {
      1: {
        1: 'SKU1',
        2: 'SKU2',
        //etc
      },
      //etc
    },
    //etc
  },
  //etc
}
```

It corresponds to products in bins on shelves, so the keys are "Area": "Rack": "Level": "Bin": "Sku"

Trouble is, when a user updates one AreaRackLevelBin to a Sku, I need to find any other location that has that sku and remove it (a sku can only be on one place).

The naive way to do this is:

```
for (let area in layout)
  for (rack in layout[area])
    for (level in layout[area][rack])
      for (bin in layout[area][rack][level])
        if (layout[area][rack][level][bin] === sku)
          layout[area][rack][level][bin] = "";
          // call whatever code updates the backend
```

But this is obviously nested for looping. I did some back of the envelope math and calculated there will only ever be about 2,250 bins to traverse (5 areas, 10 racks, 9 levels, 5 bins).

Is there a way to traverse the deepest layer of a deeply nested object without 4 layers of for loops? Heck, I guess I'm not even sure if there's a performance hit when I would absolutely need to iterate over all 2,250 bins to check anyway. One thought I had was an array of pointers to those levels, but JavaScript doesn't have pointers. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: The problem is not that I have to type `LAYOUT[A][B][C][D]`, it's that I have to iterate all the keys in nested order to find the one value. This isn't even necessarily a problem if there isn't a more time efficient method.

My thought is that I could store an array of all the deepest objects and just iterate that. I imagine that would be a reference, not a value. It just doesn't seem explicit enough for me to trust I'm not modifying the values.

Comment: Take a look at object-scan. It does exactly what you want I think (disclaimer I'm the author)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing to better illustrate what I was suggesting in the comments below. This is a what part of a very rudimentary implementation could look like:

```
const map = {}

const addAllSkusToMap = (layout) => {
  for (let area in layout)
    for (rack in layout[area])
      for (level in layout[area][rack])
        for (bin in layout[area][rack][level])
          addNewSkuToMap(sku, area, rack, level, bin)
}

const addNewSkuToMap = (sku, areaKey, rackKey, levelKey, binKey) => {
  map[sku] = { areaKey, rackKey, levelKey, binKey }
}

const getSkuLocation = (sku) => {
  return map[sku]
}
```

So after creating the map initially via 1 complete traversal of your object tree, if you want to get the location of a sku it's as simple as accessing `map[sku]` (which is O(1)).

You'll have to make sure to update `map[sku]`'s value when a user moves the sku to a different bin.

Comment: But with this I still have to have the path. Which means I still have to iterate. Is there a way to find all of a particular sku (the deepest nested value) without iterating?

Comment: Like nested `for`'s it has its own drawbacks. But ... imho it sounds like maybe an option in your case, considering (I'm assuming) your maximum depth is a known value.

Comment: My maximum depth is a known value. I'm starting to think the nested for's is the only real way to go. It sounds like any alternative solution would have just as much performance hit. Even if I had an array of pointers to the leaf nodes, I'd still have to iterate through all of them and it would be just as many iteration as the nested loop.

Comment: Well, a HashMap of SKUs locations could be of value. Sure, would have another thing to update (the HashMap). But after you create the HashMap you’re reference time would be essentially O(1).

Comment: That's a good idea, like basically construct a hashmap of skus to paths. Thanks!

Comment: @malan88 precisely! and no problem. i hope it works out for you.

Comment: It did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have iterate throw your keys but you can do it effectively.
Based on [this](https://medium.com/data-scraper-tips-tricks/safely-read-write-in-deeply-nested-objects-js-a1d9ddd168c6) like that:

```js
let setValue = (propertyPath, value, obj) => {

let properties = Array.isArray(propertyPath) ? propertyPath : propertyPath.split(".")

  if (properties.length > 1) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(properties[0]) || typeof obj[properties[0]] !== "object") obj[properties[0]] = {}
    return setValue(properties.slice(1), value, obj[properties[0]])
  } else {
    obj[properties[0]] = value
    return true // this is the end
  }

}

let obj = {
  root: {
    child: {
      child1: {
        variable: null
      }
    }
  }
}

setValue("root.child.child1.variable", true, obj)

console.log(obj)
```